# How the depth[Mpc] is obtained from the redshift

Tags: galaxy, distances, redshift

I read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3919.pdf).  In this paper, they show the three-dimensional distribution of the [OII] emitters. [image]
It is mentioned that The depth in z-axis is converted from the redshift, which is estimated from the ratio of [O II] emission lines measured with NB912 filter to that measured with NB921 filter. This is shown in this fig
[image]

I have this doubt that how to get this depth in *Mpc* from the **redshift**. They mentioned that the centre of galaxy cluster at z=1.5.